# Access elements in matrix when it is called from a function in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am having problems with this line

```
for(int &vecino: lista_vecinos[hormiga])
```

I want  to go ever each element in `hormiga` column from `lista_vecinos`.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <time.h>  // libreria para el uso de time() 
#include <random>  
using namespace std;

int n=30; //número de nodos o ciudades

int** vecinos(int, int)
{
    int** lista_vecinos = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lista_vecinos[i] = new int[n]; 
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){ lista_vecinos[i][j] = (j); }
    }
    return lista_vecinos;
}    

int main()
{
    int** lista_vecinos = vecinos(n,n);  //Call function    
    for  (int &vecino: lista_vecinos[hormiga]) //For each element in row     "hormiga" from LIsta_vecinos
    {
        r1+=probabilidad_acumulada[hormiga][vecino]= r1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you define what "Problems" you are having?

Comment: It gives Error no matching  function for call  to begin (int**&)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is not an object you can iterate over.

`vecinos` returns `int**`.  `lista_vecinos[hormiga]` is of type `int*`.  `int*` is not something a `for(:)` loop can iterate over, party because there is no way to determine when it ends.

Stop using raw arrays when you don't understand them.  Use `std::vector<int>` for a one-dimensional array, and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for a two-dimensional (jagged) array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecinos(int a, int b)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> retval;
  retval.resize(a);
  for( std::vector<int>& v:retval ) {
    v.resize(b);
    for( int i = 0; i < b; ++i )
      v[i] = i;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Note that your code doesn't compile for other unrelated reasons, such as `hormiga` not being declared anywhere.

Comment: Thank you!! this works perfectly.  I was using those arrays because I wanted that my function returned me a matrix. I have some question why it is used for( std::vector<int>& v:retval ) instead of something like  for( int j = 0; j < a; ++j )?  And, the size of retval cannot be set  as  a*b in one line??